# Why Flink run slower at standalone cluster than run in IDE?

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-batch

I have run my Flink program (in Scala) both in my IDE (Intellij) and standalone cluster. In my program, I print out the running time. I got 20s when running in IDE and 74s when running in standalone cluster. I am very confused why it takes so much times running in a cluster with 10 parallelism. I am trying to compare Flink performance with Spark basically. Can someone help me to understand how can it happen ? Thank you.

**Added** :

Sample of my program can be found [here](https://github.com/isthabenahadirani/trance-flink/blob/master/executorFlink/src/main/scala/flinkutils/generated/Test2Agg2Spark.scala). Time that is printed in the console for this particular code is as below:

- Flink (IDE, Windows) : 2550ms
- Flink (standalone cluster, WSL2 Ubuntu) : 9076ms

Config for Flink standalone cluster that I've changed:

- jobmanager.memory.process.size: 2600m
- taskmanager.memory.process.size: 5728m
- taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 20
- parallelism.default: 4
- the rest config use default values.

Run flink jar :
flink run --class flinkutils.generated.Test2Agg2Spark ./target/scala-2.12/executorflink_2.12-0.1.jar

Comment: Can you share what the program is doing and how it is configured in both cases? There are many factors that could possibly explain this.

Comment: Hi @DavidAnderson, I have shared my programs and Flink config above. Hope it can make clearer. Thank you for your help.

Comment: does it because I am running Flink cluster on WSL2 Ubuntu ? @DavidAnderson

Answer (score 1):

One factor affecting the performance is that when run in the IDE everything is running within a single JVM, and data is shipped around in memory. Whereas with the cluster, the data is going through the TCP stack.

But this is a complex scenario, and many other factors may also be negatively impacting performance.

FWIW, Flink SQL gets good performance on the TPC-H benchmark (if properly configured).